# serial/parallel communication with weighing scale from within browser

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net MVC4 application to automate a production workflow.
my client would prefer the solution to be "zero footprint", so completely running in browser.

One of the issues I can't imagine how to handle is to get data from a weighing scale connected to the client's serial/parallel port from within the page.
(Obviously this can't be done from the web backend ... )

I've been digging around, assuming this could be possible through javascript/jquery, but since this is running sandboxed within the browser, I'm assuming to get stuck that way ...

One of the approaches I considered was writing a self-hosted WCF webservice to run on the client that has the scale attached (hosted by a windows service or console app or so) that exposes the scale readout. Theoretically, that would allow me to consume the webservice in the IIS backend in my MVC C# code and serve it back to the client.

The only issue with this approach is that this would require the application to be hosted locally, where we'd prefer to have it hosted by an external provider.

Is there no way to handle this on the client side exclusively?
I can't imagine I'm the first person running into this, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for by digging around on the web ...

Any thoughts ?

Thanks in advance! Stijn, Belgium

Comment: You cannot interact with custom hardware from pure client-side code.  Browser extensions may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely must have a process running on the system that has access to hardware to support reading from any hardware interface.  You have a lot of options there- it could be a local service running that can read the serial port and expose a simple HTTP endpoint to the browser.  You can also do ActiveX-style controls for IE or browser extensions for Chrome:

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb.html

Comment: Hi Dave, So my approach of creating a WCF service to run on the client that exposes an http endpoint would not be such a bad idea? they only thing I have a hard time seeing is how to consume that from within the browser ... How would one achieve that? through jquery.ajax() directing to that endpoint and doing a partial page refresh on the callback or so ?

Comment: I would design an install program to look for an open HTTP port and designate it as a reserved port for your application.  You might look into Katana as an option for a light server that doesn't require IIS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451439.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow-up:

I ended up creating a user-control that reads out the COM-port through PInvoke of **CreateFile** to open the COM-port ...

Works great, no hassle with an external process running on the client etc ...

Does require full trust in the browser, but that's acceptable, since it'll run on clients under our control ...

grtz,
Stijn

Comment: Hi, Glad you found a solution, I seem to be stuck with the same issue, and was wondering if you could please provide more details on your solution, particularly what you mean by 'user-control'.
Perhaps you can point me to whichever resources you used for your solution? Thanks.